# connect circuit to a cigarette lighter

Tags: power-supply, noise, decoupling-capacitor

I have a PCB that I put together and it works pretty well so far. My big issue now is I would like to power it from the cigarette lighter on my airplane.

The cigarette lighter inside a car sits on a somewhat "well-regulated" bus. But, inside a 1975 Cessna 172, the cig lighter sits on a bus that is a very unclean power bus. There are strobe lights going off, the avionics put surges on the bus. The power bus in the airplane is pretty basic.

My circuit uses an Analog Devices LT8640S step-down converter to take a wide range of power and regulate it down to 5V. It works well.  I've been powering this from my bench-top power supply.

But, I'm concerned about how to properly protect my circuit from the main power bus. I'm thinking a crowbar circuit to protect against an over-voltage situation on my side would be helpful.

But, how does on handle decoupling noise and other transients on the bus before they get to my step-down converter?

Comment: Don't forget about protecting the aircraft, especially the noise floor of the VHF AM radios, from the switcher.

Comment: Any reason not to just charge an off-the-shelf 5V USB lipo power bank from the 12V circuit and use the power bank as your PCB's power supply?

Answer (score 0):

The LT8640S will operate up to 42V which should protect your circuits against a noisy 12V bus.  It is a voltage regulator after all so its job is to clean up the noise.  The only concern might be protection from load dumps or high voltage transients when inductive loads (fan motors etc) turn off.  You can place a transorb in front of your LT8640S (that is from 12V to gnd).  To protect the transorb, put a fuse in the 12V line to protect your 12V bus in the event the transorb fails shorted.

Comment: I found a paper on transorbs for avionics that should help.   http://www.mglavionics.com/Transorb_power_supply_surge_protection.pdf